# How can I group rows in Table by day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Table with columns of

| Timestamp | Region |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-06 01:00:00.0000000 | East |
| 2022-10-06 03:00:00.0000000 | East |
| 2022-10-06 05:00:00.0000000 | West |
| 2022-10-06 01:00:00.0000000 | East |
| 2022-10-07 05:00:00.0000000 | West |
| 2022-10-08 05:00:00.0000000 | East |
| 2022-10-09 01:00:00.0000000 | West |
| 2022-10-09 01:00:00.0000000 | East |

So I want to group the table by 'Day' and  'Region'

| Timestamp | Region | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-06 | East | 3 |
| 2022-10-06 | West | 1 |
| 2022-10-07 | West | 1 |
| 2022-10-08 | East | 1 |
| 2022-10-09 | West | 1 |
| 2022-10-09 | East | 1 |

So I try this with SQL

```
SELECT 
[region], 
CONCAT( datepart(YEAR, [Timestamp]), '-',  datepart(MONTH, [Timestamp]), '-', datepart(DAY, [Timestamp])) AS dayEvent,
FROM Table
GROUP BY [region], [dayEvent]
```

But I get error saying 'Timestamp is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Can u please tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: Which rdbms are you using (mysql, sql server, etc). No need to concat pieces of date.

Comment: I am using sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server you can simplify by the use of *cross apply* which allows you to reference it in the *select* and *group by*, and the *convert* function to extract the required date:

```
select ts [Timestamp], Region, Count(*) [count]
from t
cross apply(values(Convert(Date, [Timestamp])))x(ts)
group by ts, Region;
```

Example [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Esx2nrvO)

Comment: Thanks @Stu. How can I group by `month` in 'ts`?

Comment: If you want the month instead of date just extract the month using `month([Timestamp])` in the cross-apply.

Answer (score 1):

We can `cast(Timestamp as date)` and that would give us the results we want.

```
select   cast(Timestamp as date) as Timestamp
        ,Region
        ,count(*)                as count
from     t
group by cast(Timestamp as date), Region
```

| Timestamp | Region | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-06 | East | 3 |
| 2022-10-08 | East | 1 |
| 2022-10-09 | East | 1 |
| 2022-10-06 | West | 1 |
| 2022-10-07 | West | 1 |
| 2022-10-09 | West | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZojCJM4x)